# R Quarto not rendering

Tags: quarto, oserror

I have R Quarto documents in two folders. One is working fine and rendering.

The other file, which was working fine, is now showing an error. I have tried uninstalling and installing R and R Studio, didn't help.

Error message:

ERROR: Error executing 'D:\R-4.3.1\bin\x64\Rscript.exe': The pipe is being closed. (os error 232)

R installation:
Version: 4.3.1
Path: D:/R-4.3.1
LibPaths:
- D:/R-4.3.1/library
knitr: (None)
rmarkdown: (None)

The rmarkdown package is not available in this R installation.
Install with install.packages("rmarkdown")

Error occurred during cleanup: PermissionDenied: Access is denied. (os error 5)

I tried uninstalling and installing R and R Studio. I also tried making a new R Quarto document. None of it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Are you working on a corporate/shared drive? Or any other directory, where you don't have administrative rights?

I had the same issue (os error 5) in a Quarto document placed in a corporate drive and was unable to render the HTML-document from there.
Yet, moving the source Quarto document to a local directory (i.e. desktop), rerunning and re-rendering the document, solved the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mathias. Yes, its a shared folder. I am using Google Drive across computers. I'll try to implement your solution. Thanks again.